# How to use a table from 1 database in another database?

Tags: postgresql

We have a table of user accounts in one database and we would like to use the same user accounts in a different database.

I have come up with a way of doing this that involves exporting the user accounts to CSV and then copying them into the other database, which seems to work, but is there a way of doing this so future changes are automatically there such as symlinking the users table in the other database?

Comment: You can use a foreign table

Answer (score 0):

@user2099762, You can use dblink functionality to access tables in another database:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/contrib-dblink-function.html

Comment: Better use the foreign table wrapper instead of dblink. https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/postgres-fdw.html